# Corrupted Presentation Recovered Magically

Tags: browser, microsoft-powerpoint, anti-virus, repair

When I tried opening the file directly, PowerPoint said file is **corrupted**. Tried to repair it but it was in vain.

Then I opened it with google chrome browser. The same file downloaded again. When I tried to open the **downloaded file** directly with PowerPoint, alas! it opened.

Same thing happens when I downloaded it from Free Download Manager (FDM). (Actually I tried opening it using Firefox. Since Firefox is integrated with FDM that happened.)

But when I tried to open it using Internet Explorer ("Save As..") the newly *saved file* was as the same as the original. For Microsoft Edge nothing happened.

> ### This was what PowerPoint had to say:
>
> The presentation cannot be opened. Your antivirus program may prevent you from opening the presentation. To fix this problem, make sure your antivirus program is current and working correctly. If the problem persists and the presentation is from someone that you trust, turn off your antivirus program, and then try to open the presentation again. If you do this, make sure you turn on your antivirus program again after you open the presentation.

So I turned "Real Time Protection" off in my Virus Guard (Defender) and tried to open it again but the same message popped up.

There were some other *.pptx* files in the same folder of the original file and they open just fine.

Although the original file doesn't open in PowerPoint, it's shown in the preview pane without a problem.

The HEX files of both the original and the *cleaned* are identical.

My problems are:

- Why PowerPoint treat the two files differently?(Although the HEX files are identical.)

  1. Is there some cleaning mechanism involved when we download a file?
     (For instance when a download is completed in Edge, it does a further processing saying "Scanning".)
  2. If so, what are the changes made to the file by that cleaning process?
     (The properties were identical for both original and *cleaned* one.)
  3. Is there any inbuilt security system in PowerPoint?
  4. Are there any other factors/reasons contributing to this scenario?
  5. What are the other situations in which this phenomena can be exploited?

Comment: Then how was it possible? @Ramhound

Comment: if there's no difference between the cleaned one and the original, how come PowerPoint says original is corrupted and opens *cleaned* one without a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51268/discussion-between-amila-pasan-and-ramhound).

Comment: Where did I asked about edge?

Comment: It wasn't about Edge, but browsers in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If PowerPoint gives you error messages when you try to open a file you've downloaded from the internet, right-click the file's icon, choose PROPERTIES, then on the General tab of the Properties dialog box, check for a button marked UNBLOCK.

If it's there, click it.  Close the Properties dialog box and try opening the file again.